# How to add anchor jump tags to my headers using data tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm trying to make this more generic, not sure how to use the data tags...

My headers with < a > anchor tags looks like this:

```
<h4>Prohibited items<a class="anchor" id="prohibited-items" href="#prohibited-items" onclick="$('#prohibited-items').ScrollTo();"></a></h4>
```

I would like my < h4 > headers to look like this:

```
<h4 data-anchor="prohibited-items">Prohibited items</h4>
```

**How can I inject anchor tags dynamically to all the < h4 > that contain the data-anchor tag?**

UPDATE: this is what I ended up doing (now working with jQuery 3):

```
// Generate anchor tags where data-anchor data tag is used
// if data-anchor does not have a value the element text will be used to generate the anchor id
// for example: <h4 data-anchor>Sample title</h4> or <h4 data-anchor="custom-id">Sample title</h4>
$("[data-anchor]").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-anchor"); // Check if a custom id was provided
    if (id != null && id.replace(/ /g, "") === "") {
        id = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "-"); // Remove special characters
        id = id.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase(); // Replace spaces with "-"
    }
    if (!$(this).hasClass("cursor-pointer"))
        $(this).addClass("cursor-pointer");
    // console.log("id = " + id + ", text = " + text);
    $(this).attr("onclick", "$('html, body').stop().animate(" +
        "{ scrollTop: $('#" + id + "').offset().top }, '400', 'swing'); " +
        "document.location='#" + id + "'; return false;");
    $(this).html("<div class='anchor-space'>" + text + "</div><a " +
        "class='anchor-marker no-print' " +
        "id='" + id + "' " +
        "href='#" + id + "' " +
        "></a><span " +
        "class='anchor-symbol no-print'" +
        "></span>");
});
```

and

```
.anchor-marker {
top: -110px;
position: relative;
display: block;
}
.anchor-space {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.anchor-symbol {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    &:before {
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        content: "\f13d"; // http://fontawesome.io/icon/anchor/
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: using `innerHTML` of javascript or `.html()` function of jQuery

Comment: Please remove your answer from the question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
$('[data-anchor]').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-anchor');
  $(id).scrollTo();
});
```

or:

```
$('[data-anchor]').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var id =$(this).attr('data-anchor');
  $(this).html(text+'<a class="anchor" id="'+id.substring(1)+'" href="'id'" onclick="$('+id+').ScrollTo();"></a>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("h4[data-anchor]").on('click', function(){
 var anchorElement = $(this).data("anchor");
 $(anchorElement).scrollTo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below:

Put "Prohibited items" text inside span like

```
<h4><span>Prohibited items</span><a class="anchor" id="prohibited-items" href="#prohibited-items" onclick="$('#prohibited-items').ScrollTo();"></a></h4>
```

The jayascript code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('h4').each(function(){
         $(this).data('anchor',$(this).find('span').text());
       });
});
```

Hope this helps.